# Point to html page after last slide of html5 gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I've a problem with a html5 gallery.
This gallery must point to a html page after last slide transition.
I have 3 slides (a sort of splash composed by images) and after the third image I want to redirect on my website's home page.

```
<div class="slider">
    <figure class="active">
        <img src="gallery/hp-1.jpg" onload="imageLoaded();" alt="image 1" />
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="gallery/hp-2.jpg" alt="image 2" />
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="gallery/hp-3.jpg" alt="image 3" />
    </figure>
</div>

<script>
(function($, window, document, undefined) {

    var Html5Gallery = {

        isTransitionInProgress : false,
        isMusicPlaying         : false,
        fMusicPlayer           : null,
        nextSwitch             : null,
        fMusicPlayerIsLoaded   : false,
        isWindowReady          : false,
        imageIsStillLoading    : true,

        init : function(element, options) 
        {
            var self = this;
            $(window).ready(function(){
                self.isWindowReady = true;
                if (!self.imageIsStillLoading) {
                    self.handleReadness();
                }
            });

            this.options = $.fn.extend({}, $.fn.Html5Gallery.options, options);
            this.imageIsStillLoading = true;

            $(window).bind("resize", this.handleResizing);

            window.flashIsLoaded = function() {
                self.flashPlayerLoaded();
            };

            window.imageLoaded = function() {

                if(!$("figure.active img").get(0).complete)
                {
                    self.isTransitionInProgress = true;
                    setTimeout(imageLoaded, 100);     
                    return;
                }

                self.imageIsStillLoading = false;

                if (self.isWindowReady) {
                    self.handleReadness();
                }
            };

        },

        nextImage: function(e)
        {
            if (this.isTransitionInProgress)
            {
                return;
            }

            this.cancelNextScheduledImage();

            var from = $("figure.active");
            var to = (from.next().is("figure") ? from.next() : from.parent().children(":first"));
            this.isTransitionInProgress = true;
            this.switchImages(from, to);
        },

        prevImage: function(e)
        {
            if (this.isTransitionInProgress)
                return;

            var from = $("figure.active");
            var to = (from.prev().is("figure") ? from.prev() : from.parent().children(":last"));
            this.isTransitionInProgress = true;
            this.switchImages(from, to);
        },

        switchImages: function(from, to)
        {
            var self              = this;
            var isNextImageLoaded = to.children("img").get(0).complete;
            if (isNextImageLoaded)
            {
                from.stop().fadeOut(self.options.transitionSpeed, function(){

                    from.removeClass("active").css("display", "none");
                    to.addClass("active");
                    self.handleResizing();
                    to.hide().fadeIn(self.options.transitionSpeed, function(){
                        self.isTransitionInProgress = false;
                        self.scheduleNextImage();
                    });
                });

                return;
            }

            $("#loading").hide().fadeIn(self.options.transitionSpeed, function(){
                from.removeClass("active").css("display", "none");
                to.addClass("active");
                if (isNextImageLoaded)
                {
                    self.handleResizing();
                    self.hideLoading();
                }   
                else
                {
                    imageLoaded();
                }
            });
        },

        hideLoading: function()
        {
            var self = this;

            $("#loading").fadeOut(this.options.transitionSpeed, function(){
                self.isTransitionInProgress = false;
                self.scheduleNextImage();
            });
        },

        cancelNextScheduledImage: function()
        {
            clearTimeout(this.nextSwitch);
            this.nextSwitch = null;
        },

        scheduleNextImage: function()
        {
            var self = this;
            this.cancelNextScheduledImage();
            if (!this.isTransitionInProgress && this.options.autoSwitch)
            {
                this.nextSwitch = setTimeout(function(){
                    self.nextImage();
                }, this.options.pauseOnPictureFor);
            }
        },

    };
})
</script>
```

You can download [here](http://www.simbolproject.com/gallery.zip) the html file complete with all code.

Thank you for your help.
Simone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook into the logic which loops back to the first slide. This works by checking whether the next element is a `figure` element and, if not, grabbing the first `figure` element and switching to it. You can override this logic to redirect your page after the last slide has displayed like so (not tested):

```
nextImage: function(e)
{
    if (this.isTransitionInProgress)
    {
        return;
    }

    this.cancelNextScheduledImage();

    var from = $("figure.active");
    // var to = (from.next().is("figure"); ? from.next() : from.parent().children(":first"));
    var to = from.next(); 

    if (to.is("figure")) {
        this.isTransitionInProgress = true;
        this.switchImages(from, to);
    } else {
        window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }
},
```

I've hardcoded the URL in place for speed and clarity, but a better approach would be to pass the URL to the plugin via the `options` object it receives as a parameter of the `init` method.

Comment: Thanks to the availability and the time dedicated. I'm not versed in javascript. I try to add the code tha you advice but this not seem to work. This is the [Gallery](http://www.simbolproject.com/gallery). After the third image, the loops still continue.

Comment: Can you post a version with the plugin code un-minified? Ideally as a http://jsfiddle.net if at all possible?

Comment: Will have a play on the train on the way home.

Comment: Can't get a working implementation going locally with what you've given me. If you could you put together a tested working zip or (ideally) a jsfiddle, I will be able to help you.

Comment: I update the gallery working [here](http://www.simbolproject.com/gallery_ok),
and a zip [here](http://www.simbolproject.com/gallery_ok.zip).

I hope the uploaded files are right!

Thank you so much for help and availability!

Comment: No worries Simone. Actually, it was my mistake and a lesson in why it's important to test. I've updated the code in my answer and tested it successfully in your local build.

Comment: Thank you. I update the code in main.js but it still not working. Something wrong? I update my links to zip and test page, and as you can see after third image the gallery not redirect to the page.

Comment: Okay, I'm guessing you're not actually building the minified version of the component yourself. If that's the case, you need to replace the main-min.js reference in index.html with a reference to main.js. If you need it minified you'll need to run the updated version of main.js through a minifier yourself.

Comment: Ok, it was enough to add main.js in index.html to see gallery work! Now there are both reference main.js and main-min.js in index.html. Thank you very much, you have been really helpful!

Comment: No problem Simone. Glad to assist.